# wicket form changes are not visible when setDefaultFormProcessing(true)

Tags: java, forms, button, wicket

I have a form in wicket which has two buttons. I would like one to have validation over the fields (if they are left null or not) which I already did. Now I would like the second button NOT to have this validation. I have seen few examples where people use the method `setDefaultFormProcessing()` which is a method of class Button in wicket.

However when I use this method my form seems to also ignore changes done in the fields of the form.

Any idea how I actually can achive bypassing the validation but still be able to see changes in my form??

Thanks!!

Comment: I'm sure you'll get plenty of ideas as soon as people see your code.

Comment: Can you share your code so that we can sorted this out?

Answer (score 3):

This is the defined behavoir. If data is not valid it is not possible update model anyway. Consider an example when you have a date field and you type there '99/9/YYYYY' that is not a valid date, thus wicket has no chance just to bypass validation and update model. The only chance is to keep input data as String and give you an option, how to convert or update model by your own implementation.

If you have a reference to your form components, you could invoke updateModel().

See http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Turn-off-form-validation-td1877661.html

And check API doc for FormComponent that is a base class of all fields and other form components. https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/7.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/FormComponent.html

Comment: Basically I want to add in my form an autocomplete button where I get the inputs given by the user when the button is pressed and complete the rest of the fields accordingly.